# Вызов копирующего конструктора для временного объекта

Tags: c++

Почему следующая программа выводит `11422`, а не `13242`?

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    A() { std::cout << '1'; }
    ~A() { std::cout << '2'; }
    A(const A&) { std::cout << '3'; }
    void foo() { std::cout << '4'; }
} x;

int main() {
    A(x);
    x.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что у Вас нет вызова копирующего конструктора в коде.

```
A(x);
```

Это то же самое, что

```
A x;
```

Т.е. определение локальной переменной `x` типа `A`, которая скрывает глобальную переменную `x`. Чтобы сделать именно копирование, используйте синтаксис с фигурными скобками, чтобы не сбивать с толку парсер, людей и себя:

```
A{x}
```

Подробнее об этом можно почитать в стандарте C++: [[stmt.ambig]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig) и [[dcl.ambig.res]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ambig.res), но суть проста: компилятор всегда пытается что-то объявить/определить, а если не удаётся — значит перед ним выражение.